# Symfony2: how to get data from unmapped field (within collection) in custom validator

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form which looks roughly like this: first there is the ItemType:

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array())
            ->add('item_user_role', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => 'MyBundle\Form\ItemUserRoleType',
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new ItemUserRole()
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
    ... 
}
```

Then there is the ItemUserRoleType:

```
class ItemUserRoleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'id',
                TextType::class,
                array(
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'constraints' => array(),
                )
            )
            ->add('roleid',  EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Role',
                'placeholder' => 'Select Role',
                'required' => false,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotNull(),
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            ))
            ->add('userid',  EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\User',
                'required' => false,
                'choice_label' => 'LastName',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotNull(),
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that a submitted form can either contain only userid and roleid (which is used to create a new ItemUserRole) or contain an id as well (which is used to edit an existing ItemUserRole).

My Problem is now that in my custom Validator "ItemUserRole" I need to access the ID to make sure if the ID is set, then the user is allowed to modify it. But since it is not mapped, I haven't yet found out how to do that.

What I tried was this:

```
class ItemUserRoleValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $tmp = $this->context->getRoot()->get('item_user_role')->getData()[0];
        var_dump($tmp->getId());
        return;
    }
}
```

But that returns NULL. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $value variable.

```
class ItemUserRoleValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $tmp = $value[0];
        var_dump($tmp->getId());
        return;
    }
}
```

$this->context, doesn't contain any form data, but the collection of all the constraints violations discovered at this time.

Comment: so how do I access the form data in a class constraint?

Comment: I tried that. I can get roleid and userid that way becase theyre mapped to the role and user Entities - but not the id itself

Comment: Did you dump the $value variable 'exit(dump($value))' to try to find the id ?